# how to fill an excel vertically by a list in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, reporting, birt

At the moment i'm trying to migrate a report generated by `Birt` into a downloadable Excel file. So for that im using `Apache POI` API. So im getting the same report object list and populate them using the Apache POI into a downloadable excel file and its working fine. But I've got stucked when there are individual cell rows inside a particular row in the Birt report im generating. Is this possible in Apache POI?

Below is the report section I wanna migrate to an Excel. 
Really need a good guidance for this task. Thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot]

Above `Charge`, `Qty` and `Price` columns are the problem I've faced. In birt they act as another inner table. But in here im hoping to populate those fields vertically as one value for one cell and keep the other column cells empty. Is this possible?

[image: expected outcome]

Comment: You are mistaken in your perspective. It is not that there are cells within cells, or sub-rows of a larger row, it's that the first 3 cells *span* more than one row. It is how Excel works. It is how HTML table cells work. How can you expect yourself to generate Excel worksheets from code, if you don't know how Excel works?

Comment: @Andreas, each row in the inner table its a separate record. So what is the way to achieve this in Apache POI, or is it impossible?

Comment: I already told you: In Excel, aka in POI, you do it using rowspan, e.g. row 1: Plan (rowspan 3), Address (rowspan 3), Diagnosis (rowspan 3), Charge, Qty, Price; row 2: Charge, Qty, Price; row 3: Charge, Qty, Price; row 4: starts with Plan again. --- But why are you even trying to do that, when Birt already has ability to generate Excel. Why reinvent the wheel? Or couldn't you be bothered to look at the link I provided up top to see that Birt already supports that?